# Getting and Setting values (or objects) to object path expression

Tags: c#

I would like to achieve something like the one below

```
oEmp.SetPathValue("PersonalInfo.Addresses[2].City", "Austin");
oEmp.GetPathValue("PersonalInfo.Addresses[2].City");
```

It could even be something like this (nested collection at every level and to multiple levels):

```
oEmp.SetPathValue("Info[0].Addresses[2].City", "Austin");
oEmp.GetPathValue("Info[0].Addresses[2].City");
```

Do we have any existing parser (or extension) out there (in C#) to achieve the above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the method for both, also if you are trying to pass / parse the string passed in `oEmp.SetPathValue` you are aware that you will not be able to access `PersonalInfo.Addresses[2].City' is a string at that point not an object

Comment: I have not authored any of those methods, but I am searching for similar functional existing code base anywhere.  You are right that the path is always going to be string and the set/get value could be any object.